# How to use concatRelated in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

Want to list department name then all employees working under it. need to generate report using it.

i tried using sub queries, group by, DISTINCT

Department
First Name         Last Name        Salary

Comment: Please provide your table schema, sample data, and expected output.

Comment: Also you can find many Stack Overflow posts which demonstrate use of that function: [ConcatRelated examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+concatrelated)

Answer (score 0):

First you sholud add New Module in ms access
In Access, open the code window (e.g. press Ctrl+G.)
On the Insert menu, click Module. Access opens a new module window.
Paste in the function below.
On the Debug menu, click Compile, to ensure Access understands it.

SELECT Distinct
  tbl1.field,
  ConcatRelated("tbl2.fileld","tbl2","id=""" & [Id] & """ and name=""" & [name] & """") AS Employee
FROM tbl1;